# Handling mouse input in a Java card game

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I've been working on a Java card game application where I'm trying to properly implement an MVC architecture for the sake of learning.  Currently, I've implemented models for the deck, the table, and all of the players.  I've also created viewer classes for each of the models, where each viewer displays its respective model in a JPanel.  I then have a GameViewer class, which places all of the viewers into a JFrame.

My top-level class calls Main, which creates instances of all the models and viewers. I'm now trying to implement controllers, which will use the ActionListener class to look for button clicks from the user and modify the viewers and models accordingly. I'm confused though as to how best to do this.

The design of my game is very sequential, where the game displays a message to the user, then waits for the user's input from a mouse-click, then continues, etc.  For this reason, I thought I would run the actual game in a while loop in Main, where each iteration represents a round in the game, until the game is over.

The issue is that I'm only interested in some inputs from the user at specific times.  For instance, I might display a message to the user and tell them to click the OK button to continue.  At this point, I don't care if they click on one of the cards, because I'm just looking for a click of the OK button.  At other times, I may ask the user to choose a card, in which case, I'm waiting for them to click on a card, and I'm not interested in clicks from the OK button.

I'd like to implement this without any sort of polling, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.  If I get to a point where I'm waiting for user input, do I use the wait() method to put the game thread to sleep until an event callback from an ActionListener sends a notification?

Otherwise, is using the sequential code in Main the wrong way to go about it?  Should I be implementing all of the game logic within the event callbacks from the ActionListeners?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My top-level class calls Main, which creates instances of all the models and viewers. I'm now trying to implement controllers, which will use the ActionListener class to look for button clicks from the user and modify the viewers and models accordingly. I'm confused though as to how best to do this.
>
> The design of my game is very sequential, where the game displays a message to the user, then waits for the user's input from a mouse-click, then continues, etc. For this reason, I thought I would run the actual game in a while loop in Main, where each iteration represents a round in the game, until the game is over.

This is fine, but what I would do is make your game a step-wise game (I forget the name for this) where in the game loop you change the state of the program depending on the previous state and the user input. Then have your program's behavior state-dependent. To implement this, consider creating an enum to encapsulate program state and using a [state design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to allow the program to alter behavior depending on its state.

> The issue is that I'm only interested in some inputs from the user at specific times. For instance, I might display a message to the user and tell them to click the OK button to continue. At this point, I don't care if they click on one of the cards, because I'm just looking for a click of the OK button. At other times, I may ask the user to choose a card, in which case, I'm waiting for them to click on a card, and I'm not interested in clicks from the OK button.

And here is where a state pattern would shine since with it you would allow the user to click where ever he desires, but only have your program respond to certain clicks depending on the program's state.

> I'd like to implement this without any sort of polling, but I'm not sure the best way to do this. If I get to a point where I'm waiting for user input, do I use the wait() method to put the game thread to sleep until an event callback from an ActionListener sends a notification?

Correct -- don't do polling and don't use wait() or anything else that might stop program flow.

Answer (score 1):

Swing is an event driven environment, you can't control when these events might occur, the user may click on some part of your program or push a key, you really can't control this.

Swing uses a single thread (AKA The Event Dispatching Thread) or EDT), Swing uses to to dispatch events to interested parties as well as paint requests. Any action that blocks this thread will prevent the EDT from notifying your application of events or paint requests which will make your program "hang"

You can't think of GUIs as you would something like a console program, where the input is easy to control, instead you need to lead the user based on states of your controls and, Where required, dialogs.

So...NEVER, EVER create loop that blocks the EDTor performing long running or blocking (eg IO operations) that block this thread.

NEVER, EVER, create or modify any UI components from any thread other then the EDT.

You might like to have a read through

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)